# Table listener using spring

Tags: spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, spring-annotations

Is it possible from spring to listen to table insert or update even if the table is inserted/updated outside the spring application process?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: you need to do some extra works base on your RDBMS

```
- Create triggers for each of your listening tables, this trigger   
should base on a new change on these table to update information to 
somewhere else

- Create a table (named: datalogger)to store the data come from the trigger above, for example, when table1 has new record inserted, the
trigger (named: trigger1) on table1 will be execute by RDBMS, then  
trigger1 will insert a new record into datalogger which describes
the    action event is "inserted", table name is "table1", and the
inserted    record id is "new_recordId" as example. The same process
need to be    applied for modifying action.

- On your application, create a job, which will try to query the datalogger table periodically, (1ms, 10ms,... as your requirement)
to    find is there a new record in that table, if any, read the new
record    and find out what happened with your database based on the
new record    (determine by time or auto-increment id,..)
```